# Need help in ReactJs code - filter button

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to create a filter button by ReactJs, spent a lot of times but still do not know why it's doesn't work
Here are my codePen: https://codepen.io/tinproht123/pen/gOxeWpy?editors=0110

```
  const [menuItems, setMenuItems] = React.useState(menu);
  const [categories, setCategories] = React.useState(allCategories);
  
  const filterItems = (category) =>{
    if(category === 'all'){
      setMenuItems(menu);
      return;
    }
    const newItems = menu.filter((item)=> item.category === category)
    setMenuItems(newItems);
  }
  
  return(
    <section className='container'>
      <div className='title'>
        <h1>Our menu</h1>
      </div>
      <Categories categories={categories} filterItems={filterItems}/>
      <Menu menu={menuItems}/>
    </section>
  )
}~~~
```

Answer (score 1):

I checked your code and the problem isn't in the part that you showed to us.
Instead please check your codes 103th line, on codepen. Your code seems like that:

```js
const Menu = () =>{
  return(
    <div className='menu-container'>
      {menu.map((menuItem) => {
      ....
```

Be careful to the first line, since your all menu items stays in `menu` variable, even though you made correct filtering, you're printing the result for `all` menus.

I saw that you're sending a prop to a `<Menu menu={menuItems}>....`
but you're not using it. To use this prop you should add a parameter to your `Menu` function;

```js
const Menu = ({menu}) =>{
  return(
    <div className='menu-container'>
      {menu.map((menuItem) => {
```

Just like above.

Answer (score 0):

In the `Menu` component, you're not passing any props but just rendering the const value declared on top of the file.

You're filtering exactly by categories but rendering is not showing the updated one. :)

[image]